# Build AWS authorization header of http REST API requests for Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, authorization, amazon-neptune

I need to call Neptune REST endpoint for a query with http. How can I build http request authorization with aws access key, secret id, region WITHOUT SDK?

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is the process of creating an AWS Signature Version 4 signature for your requests using an access key, secret key, region, and (if using a role) a session token.

If the intent is to NOT use an SDK, then you would need to build up the AWS Signature Version 4 signature manually [1]. Doing this process manually (example via Python [2,3]) is very error prone.  It is suggested that you use an SDK for this whenever possible [4].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-python.html

[4] https://github.com/groupme/aws4